# How to use Spirals after Patch 2.7

Tags: modeling, objects, add-on, bezier-curves

Hi my question is how do i add Turns, Radius and Height as will be seen in the picture below.

As you know if you want to use spirals you need to have them on as an addon and its really easy to use **but** now its different from the new version, in the old one it looked like this:

[image]

And here you see the old spiral tab which is easy to use and change your spiral and to place a spiral you just had "spirals" as an extra object but now you got this:

[image]

Here under "Curve" as expected you see all the spirals under "Curve Profiles" and "Add Curve:spirals"  which were also in the older version but under the Spiral tab as "Spiral Type" but now because they moved all the spiral types and removed the Spiral Tab i don't know where i can change my spiral like in the number of Turns, Height and Radius.

Comment: Well have you tried adding one spiral and see what happens? Operator options show up in the *Tool Shelf* (`T`key) like they always did, and have nothing to do with the *Add Menu* structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the options are there, just select Add curves Spirals (it doesn't matter which one, you can change them later.

[image]

The options are on the toolshelf.

It the toolshelf is not open you can press <kbd>T</kbd> to access it. Or pRess <kbd>F6</kbd> to get a floating window with the same options.